# How to create <projectname>.github.io?

Tags: github, github-pages

I want to create a project page that is its own thing. I see from [GitHub Pages documentation](https://help.github.com/en/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages) that options are

```
http(s)://<username>.github.io/<projectname>
```

or

```
http(s)://<orgname>.github.io/<projectname>
```

But I would like

```
http(s)://<projectname>.github.io
```

I seem to recall seeing others do this, e.g. to accompany their submitted research papers, as a way to display results without having them (immediately) being linked to author's names (although one could easily do some search and find the names, it provides a layer of 'good faith' anonymity).  How is this achieved?

I can see a few ways:

1. register an organization with the same name as my project
2. Apply for a domain name of myproject.github.io and then [use a custom domain](https://help.github.com/en/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages).
3. Register a new github user whose name is the name of my project.  (Perhaps this is preferable to other options.)

Neither of these is particularly appealing.  Is there any 'easier' way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily

1. Create a repo for username.github.io (you don't have to use it)
2. Create another repo for your project (name doesn't matter) and setup github pages on that
3. Setup custom domain name for that specific project using a CNAME or use username.github.io/project

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.  "or use username.github.io/project": That's the very first thing in my OP that I listed I don't want.   I've got your #1 and #2 done already.   I thought CNAMEs have to be registered through some external DNS provider (according to GitHub docs, https://help.github.com/en/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages).   How does that count as 'done easily'?

Comment: I’m saying you can use a custom domain name for specific projects. Not just username.github.io repo. This solves the problem because you don’t have to create an organization and you can still have a custom domain. To use a custom domain direct your domain name dns to github and create a CNAME file in your project repo with that domain name in it. [More Info](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain)

Comment: "direct your domain name dns"  So I need to setup a domain name dns?  Sorry, I wish I knew how to do that.  The link you shared refers to "with your DNS provider."  Who is my DNS provider if I'm on GitHub?  This sounds like we're talking about paying some outside service to register a whole new domain name. (Not easier.)  But even if I did that, they wouldn't be able to register <projectname>.github.io would they?  Because only GitHub controls subdomains of github.io, right?

Comment: Your DNS provider is the service you register your domain with. For example, namecheap or google. You are correct, you still won’t be able to to get projectname.github.io, but that won’t matter if you use a custom domain since nobody would see the repo name.